# How to create and use REST API for mobile app?

Tags: magento-1.9, rest-api

Am totally new to the magento and API's. I have gone through the [Magento Rest Api Documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html).

I have created roles and users for rest api but in the documentation it is like http://magentohost/api/rest/. I have changed `my domain` in the place of `magentohost` and given but it is showing like:

> Request does not match any route

Whether any code have to add to the link? How to do this.

Can anyone give me the clear idea?

Answer (score 0):

URL *api/rest* is only endpoint. To get specific data you have to add action URL.

For example to fetch customers you have to call :

HTTP GET *mydomain/api/rest/customers*

Example here : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/Resources/resource_customers.html

Comment: Simply giving mydomain_name/api/rest/consumer is enough or else Whether I need add any code or module in our file?

Comment: Hard to say. Maybe add some example code in your question?

Comment: I will explain clearly. I didn't add any code or module to generate rest api key. Simply I did Rest-Roles and changed the resources as All for Guest and same for Rest-Atributes. After doing this, I have given the url mydomain_name/api/rest/consumer. But its showing only "<magento_api/>". Whether I need to use any code?

Comment: Have u got cleared with my ques?